# How do I remove bitterness from bitter melon

Tags: fruit, asian-cuisine, indian-cuisine, melon

We use [bitter melon/bitter gourd](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitter_melon) for making curry. We boil bitter gourd in water couple of times to remove bitterness which is very time consuming.

Is there any better way to remove bitterness?

[image]

Comment: Cooking in a microwave, as opposed to stir frying reduces bitterness. I've never tried boiling, so can't compare.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Some people claim you can reduce the bitterness of eggplant by slicing it then salting the slices, wrapping in a clean cloth, and putting some weight on it.  The salt draws out moisture.  It's possible a similar technique would work with your bitter melon, although I had never heard of it before your question.  It might not save much time, but you wouldn't have to watch them while doing the salt treatment.

Comment: This does work with bitter melon; I have done it many times. It's a good idea to then soak it in fresh water afterwards to remove as much salt as possible and rehydrate the outer surface - time permitting

Comment: Technical term is "degorging", not to be confused with "disgorging" (which could happen with a dish where the bitter melon was insufficiently degorged) :) Also a well known technique with eggplants.

Answer (score 1):

My mom uses this technique with cucumbers and bitter melon.  Slice off the tip of the bitter melon. Then put the tip back on. Now rub the cut surfaces together in a circular motion. This draws out the moisture and bitterness from the cucumber and bitter melon.

I also heard that the longer you cook the bitter melon, the more bitter it will taste. So boiling it many times may actually make it taste more bitter.